# Проблема с captions на telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня такой код:

```py
if '/bard' in message.caption:
    response = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Bard обрабатывает запрос...")
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    file_info = bot.get_file(file_id)
    image = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    user_query_2 = message.caption.split('/bard', 1)[-1].strip()
    bard_answer_2 = bard.ask_about_image(user_query_2, image)
    bot.reply_to(message, bard_answer_2['content'])
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, response.message_id)
```

Проблема в том, что он не отправляет запрос, не даёт никаких признаков вообще, даже response сообщение не отправляет. Буду благодарен если кто-то поможет.

Comment: Ну начать стоит с логичного вопроса — а этот код вообще запускается хоть кем-нибудь?

Comment: хм, ну может быть мной

Comment: И где и как вы его запускаете и откуда вы берёте `message`?